# How to make literature review for a software implementation project?

Tags: academic-writing

I don't know if this is out of the scope of this website. I'm a student in software engineering deparment and I am supposed to make a project for a course during the semester. The first step of it is to prepare a project proposal which consists of a short description of the project, a literature review and detailed flowcharts. My question is **how to make literature review for a software implementation project.** I already did some reviews from some articles which I found from sciencedirect, and already wrote an introduction for the review. I don't know whether I have to put web links as references when I mention already existing similar projects inside the body or if it should only contain academic citations.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Related: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/5376/14704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any source that you use in your work, be it academic literature, websites, or even tv programs, needs to be cited. Similar projects are extremely relevant to what you're doing, and therefore if your source on them is a website rather than an academic work, it should definitely be cited.

When you cite a website, you include its name, link, date content was written (if stated), and the date you accessed it (since content might later be changed).

Or did you mean, do you need to include a link to the academic article you're citing? In that case, no, you don't.

Your department would have a standard  for how they want citations formatted (formats vary somewhat between fields, and between journals etc. in the same field). You can ask your advisor, he'll point you to how exactly sources should be cited.